# How to fetch data from mongodb and convert it to json object in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I want to fetch the data from mongo db and store it in a json object in node.js. The purpose is to manipulate that data which I think is quite simple if its a json objcet.
Below is the code I am using:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/MyCollection';

var data;

var findRestaurants = function (db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('demographicdetails').find().limit(10);

    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {

        if (doc != null) {
            console.dir(doc);

        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

    findRestaurants(db, function () {
        db.close();
    });
});
```

From above code, I am able to fetch the data from mongo db and `console.dir(doc)` shows me the data.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
  data = doc;
 data.forEach(function (eval) {
     //Manipulating eval
 });
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use the `toObject` function.

```
cursor.each(function (err, doc) {

    if (doc != null) {
        console.dir(doc);
        var restaurant = doc.toObject(); // use restaurant object
    } else {
        callback();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB uses JSON/BSON internally to store the data. So any query you make you should get a JSON object. I use [MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/) as the MongoDB library, which gives you back a JSON after querying.

Answer (score 0):

use toArray in mongodb client , mongodb always give json format

```
db.collection('demographicdetails').find().limit(10).toArray(function (err, aum) { 

aum.forEach(function (err, doc) {

        if (doc != null) {
            console.dir(doc);

        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
})
```